# How can I request to https://my-json-server.typicode.com/horizon-code-academy/fake-movies-api with post method and add new film details in pyhton?

Tags: python, python-requests

I tried this piece of code to request to the fake movie API with post method:

```
import requests
URL = "https://my-json-server.typicode.com/horizon-code-academy/fake-movies-api/movies"
movie_detail = {
    "Title": "The Note",
    "Year": "2000",
    "Genre":"science",
    "Abstract": "something"}
r = requests.post(url=URL, data=movie_detail)
print(r.ok)
```

but I received 'False' printed in the output.
How can I post new film detail into this fake movie API?
And when I tried to print out the value of r.text I received this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
at Function.createId (/app/node_modules/json-server/lib/server/mixins.js:57:39)
at Function.insert (/app/node_modules/lodash-id/src/index.js:47:49)
at /app/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4374:28
at arrayReduce (/app/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:683:21)
at baseWrapperValue (/app/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4373:14)
at LodashWrapper.wrapperValue (/app/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:9052:14)
at create (/app/node_modules/json-server/lib/server/router/plural.js:235:48)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:14)
```

Comment: Is there a guarantee that that fake movie api set is actually set up to handle requests?

Comment: Had some lunch and this post was still up on my screen. So I took a stab in the dark guessing at what is in the black-box underlying the fake-api site you have posted and thought, *"I'll throw an 'id' key into the dictionary and see if that makes it happy"*. It worked. Try the following payload and you'll get back an `r.ok` of `True`:  `movie_detail = {"id":10, "Title": "The Note", "Year": "2000"}` So the problem isn't your code, it's that website and bad API documentation.